# How to change input/textarea value with custom keyboard event and keyCode?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keyboard-events

I would like to populate a textarea by triggering keyboard events, such as `keydown` (I'm doing this for a test case).

I have added a snippet (below) to show the code I'm using to create and trigger the event. The event fires, but the textarea never receives the value of `keyCode` which is the letter A.

What do I need to do to see the letter in the textarea? I'm currently running the snippet in the Chrome console but it should also work in IE9.

```js
var t = document.getElementById('foo');

// Event creation
var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
event.initEvent('keydown', true, true);
event.keyCode = 65;
event.which = 65;

// Listener for demo purpose
t.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  document.getElementById('fired').value = e.type + ' fired';
});

// Event trigger
t.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<textarea id="foo"></textarea>

<br>
<input id="fired" value="">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keydown` event is fired when a key is pressed down but it's not the responsible for write the data in the `DOM` elements.

The thing is; If the user writes on the `<textarea>` first the character is added to elements value and then the `keyDown`event is triggered. However in your case you're directly triggering the event so the first step which is adding the character to the value for `<textarea>` is not happening.

You have two options, do it in the browser way write the value and then dispatch the event

```
t.value = t.value + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
t.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  document.getElementById('fired').value = e.type + ' fired';
});
```

Or also you can write the value of the `<textarea>` on the `keyDown` event:

```
// Listener for demo purpose
t.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  t.value = t.value + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
  document.getElementById('fired').value = e.type + ' fired';
});
```

however if you want to use this second approach for user interaction it's a nonsense because in the case that the users inputs the data, the data will be write it twice (one for the user input and the another one in the event).

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you! You are right about the flow of events and my lack of understanding this was the problem. Like you say, the keyboard event is fired **after** the user interaction, when the value is already set. The event.keyCode is simply a piece of information.

Comment: @TJ nice to help you `:)`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Why does not the value change after triggering `keydown`?

In short: you can't change the value of `input`/`texarea` with dispatching `KeyboardEvent` programmatically.

How actually do chars come into `input`? On MDN you can find the description of [Keyboardevent sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key#keyboardevent_sequence) (assuming that `preventDefault` is not called):

> - A `keydown` event is first fired. If the key is held down further and the key produces a character key, then the event continues to be emitted in a platform implementation dependent interval and the `KeyboardEvent.repeat` read only property is set to true.
> - If the key produces a character key that would result in a character being inserted into possibly an `<input>`, `<textarea>` or an element with HTMLElement.contentEditable set to true, the `beforeinput` and `input` event types are fired in that order. Note that some other implementations may fire `keypress` event if supported. The events will be fired repeatedly while the key is held down.
> - A keyup event is fired once the key is released. This completes the process.

So, `keydown` leads to `input` event by default. But that is true only for [trusted events](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#trusted-events):

> Most untrusted events will not trigger default actions, with the exception of the `click` event... All other untrusted events behave as if the `preventDefault()` method had been called on that event.

Basically trusted events are those initiated by a user and untrusted events are initiated with a script. In most browsers, each event has an attribute [isTrusted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) indicating if the event is trusted or not.

#### And how to test `KeyboardEvent`s on `input`s then?

Well, first of all, think if you really need a `KeyboardEvent` handler. Maybe you can do everything in `InputEvent` handler. That means that you can just set the value of the `input` in your tests and then trigger `InputEvent`.

If you still need `KeyboardEvent` handler than it depends on what is going on in it. E.g. if you call `preventDefault` in certain conditions then you can check if it was called or not in a test using a spy. Here is an example with [sinon](https://sinonjs.org/) as a spy and [chai](https://www.chaijs.com/) as assertion library.

```js
const myEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: 'a' })
sinon.spy(myEvent, 'preventDefault')
document.getElementById('foo').dispatchEvent(myEvent)
expect(myEvent.preventDefault.calledOnce).to.equal(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Javascript sending key codes to a <textarea> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233800/javascript-sending-key-codes-to-a-textarea-element)

I had a look around and this seems more relevant than my non-relevant answer before. Sorry about that. I know this is jquery, but the premise is the same.

adding this in the event would work

```
document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
```

here it is in pure javascript [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/14en2pj1/1/)

Comment: I think that OP is asking about why the char is not appearing in the `<textarea>` not in the `<input>`.

Comment: ah in that case, i feel silly and will be back with an edit to correct